# CNAME for subdomain does not work - 404 Error

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have a subdomain hosted right now something like:

subdomain.domain.com

I need cdn-subdomain.domain.com to point to that same subdomain.  However, when I create this DNS entry:
Record Type: CNAME
Record Data: cdn-subdomain
Record Value: subdomain.domain.com

I get a 404 error not found when navigating to cdn-subdomain.domain.com  - ANY ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

If you're getting a 404, your CNAME is working just fine. If the CNAME wasn't working, you'd get an error indicating that no server could be found.

You need to set up your web server to serve the content to both domains. In Apache, you'd use a `ServerAlias` directive to tell it that `cdn-subdomain.domain.com` is an alias of `subdomain.domain.com`.

Comment: what can I do in windows server to resolve the problem?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Read the docs? I don't work with Windows Server. Key words would be "virtual host".